# Positioning issue when it comes to smaller monitors

Tags: css, html, css-float

This set up, the image gallery looks normal to me on my 27" monitor, with it being in the center of my body. Yet when I go to look at it on my 15" monitor, it's a few inches to the right. Now, I know it has something to do with the "gallery" css, because the div maybe pushes it to the right. My question is, is there a more beneficial way to keep it static despite the varying width of monitors? I was a bit confused on the two column layout prospect, seeing as how it wouldn't move to where the previous positioning was.

```
<div id="gallery">
<div class="html5gallery" data-width="400" data-height="225" style="display:none>
<img src="images/mr.magic.jpg" alt="Mr. and Mrs. Magic">
<img src="images/mr-magic-2.jpg" alt="Mr. and Mrs. Magic">
<img src="images/mr-magic-3.jpg" alt="Mr. and Mrs. Magic">
<img src="images/mr-magic-4.jpg" alt="Mr. and Mrs. Magic">
<img src="images/mr-magic-5.jpg" alt="Mr. and Mrs. Magic">
<img src="images/david.jpg" alt="Mr. and Mrs. Magic with David Copperfield">
<img src="images/david-2.jpg" alt="Mr. Magic with David Copperfield">
<img src="images/seigfried.jpg" alt="Mr. Magic with Seigfried and Roy">
</div>
</div>

#gallery {
position: relative;
left: 950px; 
top: -560px;
float: left; padding:0; margin:0 
}
```

I appreciate the time you guys take to look over these problems and can only hope for a good answer. Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Comment: Is this all your code?  You're missing a `</div>`.

Comment: Sorry, forgot I undid the one aspect of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not great at CSS but...

left:950px will mean the div will always be 950px from the left hand side of the parent div (the screen probably in your case).  So on smaller screens, it will appear further to the right.

Instead, try setting the width of your div, either using % or px, then setting the left and right margins to auto.  Something like:

```
#gallery {
position:relative;
width:50%;
margin: 0 auto;
top:-560px;
}
```